# -[__NSCFNumber addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I created a multidimensional array as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString string], [NSNumber       numberWithInt:0], [NSMutableArray array], nil];
self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    [self.dataArray addObject:subArray];
}
```

then when I try to access and change values like this

```
NSNumber *num = self.dataArray[0][1];
int numInt = [num intValue];
NSNumber *newNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numInt + 1];
[self.dataArray[0][1] addObject:newNum];
// add item to dataArray
NSMutableArray *tmpArr= self.dataArray[0][2];
[tmpArr addObject:item];
[self.dataArray[0][2] addObject:tmpArr];
```

but I'm getting

```
-[__NSCFNumber addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

what exactly is the problem, I don't understand, thanks in advance!

Comment: @HotLicks I know where it occurs, I just don't understand why...

Comment: Read the dupe.  The answers explain it.

Comment: (What is the value of `self.dataArray[0][1]`??)

Comment: "self.dataArray[0][1]" is NSNumber and NSNumber do not have API named "addObject".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line you are treating the object in the array as a NSNumber (which it obviously is):

```
NSNumber *num = self.dataArray[0][1];
```

And here you treat the exact same object like an NSMutableArray:

```
[self.dataArray[0][1] addObject:newNum];
```

That won't work, because that object is an instance of NSNumber.

I don't know what you achieve so I can't help you with the correct code, but that's where your problem is. Maybe you just wanted to write:

```
[self.dataArray[0][2] addObject:newNum];
```

You should probably stop to use an "inner array" as data storage and switch to using a proper subclass. Currently your code is pretty much unreadable, using proper Objects to store your values would improve it a lot.

---

Btw, your multidimensional array is actually just one dimensional, because you add the exact same array multiple times.

You probably want to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString string], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSMutableArray array], nil];    
    [self.dataArray addObject:subArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *num = self.dataArray[0][1];
int numInt = [num intValue];
NSNumber *newNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numInt + 1];
[self.dataArray[0][1] addObject:newNum];       // 3. also, possibly here
// add item to dataArray
NSMutableArray *tmpArr= self.dataArray[0][2];  // 1. here
[tmpArr addObject:item];                      // 2. and here
[self.dataArray[0][2] addObject:tmpArr];
```

You're getting this error because the first line I marked, `tmpArr` is actually of type `NSNumber`. `NSNumber` is a class cluster, which is why you're seeing `__NSCFNumber` throw the error. All that is, is just a private subclass of `NSNumber`.

So the error is being thrown because you're trying to call `addObject` on a type of object that doesn't support it. Personally I wouldn't store more than one type of object in an array, but I don't know exactly what you're doing.  Assuming you don't change the way you're storing things, what you can do is this:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArr= self.dataArray[0][2];  
if ([tmpArr isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class])
{
    [tmpArr addObject:item];                      
}
else 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Woops, trying to add an object to something that's not a mutable array");
}
```

You would have to do this everytime you try to store an object into an array that you're pulling out of `self.dataArray`. What this does is verify that `tmpArr` is what you think it is.

Alternatively, you could check if it responds to `addObject`

```
if ([tmpArr respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:)])
{
    [tmpArr addObject:item];
}
```

The second way doesn't care what class it is, only if the method `addObject` can be used.